# Does Spring Integration ServiceActivator work with Project Reactor Types?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor, spring-integration-amqp

I'm using Spring Integration 5.1.5 (with RabbitMQ using `spring-integration-amqp`) and I reading in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) that Spring Integration has support for [project reactor](http://projectreactor.io/) types (by this I mean `Mono`, `Flux` etc). But I cannot get this to work for [ServiceActivator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#service-activator)'s. I'm trying something like this:

```java
@ServiceActivator
public Mono<Void> myMethod(List<Message> messages) {
   Mono<Void> result = myService.doServiceStuff(messages);
   return result;
}
```

(note that I'm also trying to get `myMethod` working with `Flux<Message>` but that's a separate issue).

When `myMethod` returns `Mono<Void>` I get this error:

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:284)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:265)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:223)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Changing the method to:

```java
@ServiceActivator
public void myMethod(List<Message> messages) {
   Mono<Void> result = myService.doServiceStuff(messages);
   result.subscribe(); // This is not what I want to do
}
```

and subscribing to the reactive stream manually will make it work, however this is obviously not what I want to do. I would rather expect the `spring-integration` framework to handle the subscription.

Is this supported in Spring Integration? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what are you trying to achieve by returning `Mono<Void>` ?

When a service activator method returns any value, that value is sent to the output channel. When it's a `Mono<?>`, the send is performed when the mono completes.

Simply set the return type to `void`.

Comment: You definitelly should not expect the Framework to subscribe to that `Mono` for you. IMHO it is an abuse of Reactive Streams spec to subscribe unconditionally. You can add an `outputChannel` as a `FluxMessage` channel and then Framework will add that `Mono` as a source for an interal `Flux`. But still subscrtiption should happen from you or from some protocol, like WbFlux or RSocket.